# Freeform monitoring tools

Tags: monitoring, alerting

Can you suggest some sort of freeform monitoring tool?

I have been trying [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/), which allows you to add any metrics you like, and graph them on the spot. You don't have to define a new host, service, whatever. If all you want is to graph something, you send data, and you can immediately graph it.

I'm looking for a more sophisticated of that. Features I'm looking for:

- Setting alert thresholds
- Adding more metadata to the metrics (app, host, unit, ...)
- Have a web front end to manipulate all those things
- Rules can be made to add metadata automatically depending on the name of the metric.

It seems most systems out there, other than Graphite, all expect a lot of up front work to add metrics, and I'm looking to avoid that. If I think a metric is worth keeping later, I'll categorize it later.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com).  It's a performance monitoring tool which will graph just about anything you put into it, as it does that by default for all numeric values.  Most of the graphs however center around line graphs where the Y axis is at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com) seems to be a good match for the features you are looking for.

Comment: I thought Splunk was strictly a log file analysis tool. Can you use it to do performance monitoring as well?

Comment: Splunk can do performance monitoring using scripted input. Basically a script runs which gathers the data (via SNMP or WMI for instance) and inputs it to Splunk. If you take a look at Splunkbase (http://splunk-base.splunk.com/apps/) there are a wide variety of Splunk apps already available, so you don't have to create these scripts yourself.